# ¿De que se trata y cómo resolver el error Argument is not numeric or logical?

Tags: r

Desde una base de datos he exportado una tabla con 406.574 registros (objetos), y 119 columnas (variables) a un fichero txt.

En R importo ese fichero de la siguiente forma:

```
tabla <- read.csv("Datas/fichero.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

En la tabla hay varias columnas numéricas, una de ellas, llamémosla pagos por ejemplo, pero cuando le consulto la estructura devuelve lo siguiente:

```
str(tabla$pagos)

Factor w/ 64917 levels "0,00","0,18",..: 1 1 1 1 1 57041 1 17375 1 59911 ...
```

No me está devolviendo los datos como **números**, por lo que no puedo calcular por ejemplo el **promedio** de dicha columna.

Si ejecuto esta sentencia, me devuelve error,

```
mean(tabla$pagos)
```

> [1] NA
>   Warning message:
>   In mean.default(tabla$pagos) :
>    argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Por lo que procedo a quitar los NA, pero también me devuelve un error,

```
mean(tabla$pagos, na.rm = TRUE)
```

> [1] NA
>   Warning message:
>   In mean.default(tabla$pagos, na.rm = TRUE) :
>    argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Lo he intentado también con **colNames**, **sapply**, etc, pero siempre con el mismo resultado del error, ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

**Añado información:**

- El fichero csv tiene el dato numérico sin entrecomillar, por lo que no estaría guardado como un string.

Comment: Comprueba el fichero .csv, que los campos numéricos no vayan entrecomillados, por lo que cargarían como string.

Comment: El dato en el csv viene sin entrecomillar, edito la pregunta y añado esa información. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tu problema se puede enfocar de diferentes maneras, enfoco mi respuesta en que no puedes calcular el promedio por que es un string, mas que en la carga "correcta" del fichero.

```
tabla <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3),pagos=c("1,1","2,2","3,3") )
```

#### Comprobar que una columna es un factor string:

```
str(tabla$pagos)
 Factor w/ 3 levels "1,1","2,2","3,3": 1 2 3
```

#### Transformar formato a numero

```
# con gsub cambias comas por puntos y con numeric conviertes a numero
numeric(gsub(",", ".", "1,1"))

# Se aplica por fila en el dataframe
tabla$precios<-sapply(tabla$precios, function(x) as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", x)))

# Calcular media
mean(tabla$precios, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: ¡Genial, ha funcionado a la perfección! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda :)

Comment: de nada, en general podría resolverse con el "read.csv" pero al ver tu duda, entendí que quizás estos comandos te ayudarían no solo en tu actual problema sino en ir aprendiendo algunos trucos para el "futuro".

Answer (score 1):

Puedo imaginar que el problema fundamental que tienes es que tu archivo `csv` cumple dos condiciones

- Las columnas están separadas por `;` (verificado por como llamas a `read.csv`)
- El separador decimal es la `,` y no el `.`

Con estas dos condiciones, cuando haces: `read.csv("Datas/fichero.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ";")` importas correctamente las columnas, pero como las numéricas tienen como separador la coma, no las interpreta como números sino que las trata como una cadena, y por defecto el comportamiento de `read.csv` es convertir las cadenas en `factor`.

Entiendo que la forma óptima es corregir la lectura del archivo, indicando que el separador decimal será `,` mediante `dec=','`:

```
df <- read.csv("Datas/fichero.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ';', dec=',')
```

Comment: Efectivamente gracias a las indicaciones vuestras caí en la cuenta que R no toma los datos decimales con la coma, sino con el punto y lo toma como string, de ahí el fallo.
Pero cambiaré la forma de importar los ficheros con tus sugerencias Patricio, porque me estoy viendo en la necesidad de ir cambiando cada columna al formato correcto, lo cual es un fastidio. Muchísimas gracias!